# No. Of possible triangles

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

If there are n line segments in a plane of lengths (1,2,3,....,N) then find the no.  of triangles that can be formed from these.

Attempt: let the sides be X,Y,Z such that X < Y< Z then the cardinality of required set boils down to finding out pairs such that X + Y > Z other two inequalities are automatically satisfied. Then I drew a table for values of X,Y and Z such that the above conditions hold.And now the solution becomes clumsy and lengthy. Is there a better way? And even in this approach for Z = n , I have (n-2)*(n-3)/2 solutions. And now this n can be anything from 4 to N. So I summed this again. But the problem is I am missing many things answer is different for odd and even values of N. What's wrong with my solution. It doesn't match with the correct answer.

Comment: OEIS is your friend. http://oeis.org/A002623

Comment: Are you paying by the letter? Why abbreviate "number"? And if you do, at least pay attention to proper capitalization.

Comment: Asaf Karagila. I couldn't get you paying by letter? Definitely I would like to pay attention to proper capitalization but please be more descriptive. I am just a undergraduate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X<Y<Z$ and $X+Y>Z$,

$$Z+1\le X+Y\le Y-1+Y$$

and hence

$$Y\ge \frac{Z}{2}+1$$

The number of triangles is

\begin{align}
\sum_{Z=4}^N\sum_{Y=\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor+1}^{Z-1}\sum_{X=Z-Y+1}^{Y-1}1&=\sum_{Z=4}^N\sum_{Y=\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor+1}^{Z-1}(Y-1-Z+Y)\\
&=\sum_{Z=4}^N\sum_{Y=\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor+1}^{Z-1}(2Y-Z-1)\\
\end{align}

Note that

\begin{align}
\sum_{Y=a}^{Z-1}(2Y-Z-1)&=2\left(\frac{Z-a}{2}\right)(a+Z-1)-(Z-a)(Z+1)\\
&=(Z-a)(a-2)\\
\end{align}

So, the number of triangles is

\begin{align}
\sum_{Z=4}^N(Z-\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor+1-2)=\sum_{Z=4}^N(Z-\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)\\
\end{align}

If $N$ is even,

\begin{align}
&\;\sum_{Z=4}^N(Z-\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)\\
=&\;\sum_{k=2}^{N/2}(2k-\lfloor \frac{2k}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{2k}{2}\rfloor-1)+\sum_{k=2}^{(N-2)/2}(2k+1-\lfloor \frac{2k+1}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{2k+1}{2}\rfloor-1)\\
=&\;\sum_{k=2}^{N/2}(k-1)(k-1)+\sum_{k=2}^{(N-2)/2}k(k-1)\\
=&\;\sum_{i=1}^{(N-2)/2}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{(N-4)/2}i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{(N-4)/2}i\\
=&\;2\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{N-4}{2}\right)\left(\frac{N-4}{2}+1\right)(N-4+1)+\left(\frac{N-2}{2}\right)^2\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{N-4}{2}\right)\left(\frac{N-4}{2}+1\right)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{12}(N-2)(N-3)(N-4)+\frac{1}{4}(N-2)^2+\frac{1}{8}(N-2)(N-4)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-2)[2(N-3)(N-4)+6(N-2)+3(N-4)]\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}N(N-2)(2N-5)
\end{align}

If $N$ is odd, $N-1$ is even. So,

\begin{align}
&\;\sum_{Z=4}^N(Z-\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{Z}{2}\rfloor-1)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-1)(N-1-2)[2(N-1)-5]+(N-\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\rfloor-1)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-1)(N-3)(2N-7)+(N-\frac{N-1}{2}-1)(\frac{N-1}{2}-1)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-1)(N-3)(2N-7)+\frac{1}{4}(N-1)(N-3)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-1)(N-3)(2N-7+6)\\
=&\;\frac{1}{24}(N-1)(N-3)(2N-1)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{\min(i+j-1,n)}1=\sum_{i=2}^{n-2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\min(i-1,n-j)$$

I wrote a [program](http://dpaste.com/2XT472T) to generate data.
Then, using [this tool](https://arachnoid.com/polysolve/), this approximately sums to:-
$$
  \lfloor-0.0604688766 n^3+
   0.416618635 n^2
  -0.374999769 n +
   0.0833333333+0.5\rfloor$$

Explanation: $i$, $j$ and $k$ are the three sides of the triangle, such that $i<j<k$. Since $k\le n$, $j\le n-1$ and $i\le n-2$. Also triangle law mandates $i+j>k\implies k\le i+j-1$

Comment: Some of those indices don't make sense to me. For example If $n = 20$, $x = 10$, there is no $y$ or $z$ left to make a triangle. Does wolfram alpha take into consideration when the upper index is smaller than the lower index?

Comment: What's wrong with $y=11$, $z=12$?

Comment: Oops i did the triangle inequality in the opposite direction

Comment: But my solution still seems incorrect. Can you edit it?

Comment: Sure, let me rethink the bound. Then, I will edit it.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Corrected! I made an *off-by-1* mistake

Comment: Wait, $k$ cannot exceed $N$, what happens if $i+j-1 > N$. We have over counted in this rather elegant looking solution. We need to subtract $i+j-N$ every time $i+j > N$

Comment: Did you read that answer depends if n is odd or even? Look into question.

Comment: We need to subtract off $\sum_{i=1}^{ N/2-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N-i} 1$ when $N$ is even and $\sum_{i=1}^{ (N-1)/2}\sum_{j=i+1}^{N-i} 1$ when N is odd

Comment: Yeah answer depends on the parity of $N$

Comment: Your answer doesn't match with one given.

Comment: I deleted my answer?

Comment: (n-3)(n-1)(2n-1)/24 for odd n and n(n-2)(2n-5)/24 for a even n